# How do I claim my additional Economic Impact Payment if I married after getting the first?

Tags: united-states, tax-credit, covid-19

I received the original EIP last spring, then later on in the year, I got married. Early in 2021, I received the $1,200 for the second EIP, but I want to claim the additional $1,200 now that I have a spouse. How do I do this?

Comment: Did your spouse get money the first time?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep no.

Comment: There is no additional EIP for ‘having a spouse’. Your spouse might claim one, but there is probably a reason they didn’t get it before, and this reason might be still valid

Answer (score 1):

If your spouse is eligible for the 2020 payment but did not receive it, he/she can claim the [Recovery Rebate Credit](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/recovery-rebate-credit) when filing federal taxes.